# How to add border to li include the number?

Tags: html, css

How should I do border to `ol li` elements for each `li` include the number?

I read a `XML` file that contain list of questions and try to add `ol li` on HTML dynamically.

HTML

```
<div class="faq_row_holder">
    <ol class="faq_row"></ol>
</div>
```

JS

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < size; i++) {
   var question = xml.find('row').eq(i).find('question').text();
   $('.faq_row').append(" <li class='quest' ><a class='faq_row_question'>"+ question + "</a></li> <br>");
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set the `list-style-position` to `inside`.

```css
ol {
  list-style-position:inside;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

li {
  border:1px solid
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: This is one of those CSS styles I keep forgetting exists.

Comment: To fast for me :P @Mosh Feu

Answer (score 1):

I removed the Jquery because I do not think it was relevant to answer the question. All you have to do is add `list-style-position:inside;` in your style sheet.

```css
ol li {
  list-style-position:inside;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="faq_row_holder">
  <ol class="faq_row">
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test2</li>
    <li>test3</li>
    <li>test4</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.
regards